# unable to copy paste on Google compute engine sshed on my browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am unable to copy and paste text copied on my clipboard to the google cloud compute engine instance which I have accessed on my browser.

I have tried firefox and chrome both but it is not working.

I have tried cntrl+c and cntrl+v but it dosent work.

Do i need to change some system settings ?

Answer (score 2):

you can copy text from Cloud Shell (I'm assuming you mean that) by selecting text with the mouse (some scissors icon flashes then), and one can paste text with `<Ctrl> + <V>`... when trying to paste into there, be careful not to trigger the copy command (eg. by first positioning the cursor and only hitting `<Ctrl> + <V>`, without clicking onto text)... also see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/), for further details.